# MariaDB CREATE TABLE DATA DIRECTORY のエラー原因

Tags: linux, mariadb

Linux環境、MariaDBでdatadir とは別のディレクトリにテーブル/データファイルを作成しようとしています。
(CREATE TABLE .. DATA DIRECTORY 文を使用)
mariadbdプロセスはmysqlユーザで実行されており、DATA DIRECTORY
対象候補のディレクトリは、ls -lの結果が以下のようになっています。
以下のようなSQLでテーブル作成を試みましたが、(A)のディレクトリは成功し、(B)は失敗しています。

SQL: CREATE TABLE t1 (c1 INT PRIMARY KEY) ENGINE=xxxx DATA DIRECTORY = 'yyyy';
(A) drwx------ mysql mysql /mysqldata/ ->成功
(B) drwx------ mysql mysql /home/mysql/data/ ->失敗(以下のエラー)
ERROR 1 (HY000): Can't create/write to file '/home/mysql/data/t1.MYD' (Errcode: 13 "Permission denied") # MyISAM
ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table `test`.`t1` (errno: 168 "Unknown (generic) error from engine") # InnoDB
エラーログには以下のようなメッセージが出力されました。(InnoDBの場合)
[ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 13 in a file operation.
[ERROR] InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to the directory.

(A)(B)のディスクは異なりますが、いずれも容量に余裕はあります。
この成否を分けている要因はなんでしょうか?
(B)の方にデータファイルを作成するためには、どのような設定が必要でしょうか?

OS: RHEL 7.9
SELINUX: disabled
MariaDB: 10.5.9

- variables:

  - have_symlink: YES
  - datadir: /var/lib/mysql/
  - innodb_file_per_table: ON

その他、回答にあたり必要な情報がありましたらコメントいただけますと幸いです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: `/home` 配下ではなく、`/tmp/mysql/data` など別のディレクトリで試した場合はどうなりますか？

Comment: ご質問ありがとうございます。/tmp/mysql/data配下では成功しました。なお、(A)(B)およびdatadirはすべて別のボリュームです。(/tmpも別ですね)